# TimeSpan rounds off to 3 decimal positions

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

For the below line :

```
decimal sec = (decimal)TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(.8).TotalSeconds;
```

i expect sec = 0.0008 , but it gets rounded of to 3 decimal positions and gives result as 0.001 , any workarounds.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ScRs0Y

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.frommilliseconds?view=netframework-4.8), `FromMilliseconds` rounds to the nearest millisecond:

> Therefore, value will only be considered accurate to the nearest
>   millisecond.

*Note the docs are correct only for .NET Framework. .NET Core 3.x will work as the OP was hoping for (returns 0.0008, contrary to the docs).*

If you want this to work in .NET 4.x - consider multiplying the milliseconds by 10,000 (`TicksPerMillisecond`) and then call `FromTicks` (or the constructor) rather than `FromMilliseconds`:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ticksPerMillisecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        decimal sec = (decimal)TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(.8).TotalSeconds;
        decimal sec2 = (decimal)TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)(0.8 * ticksPerMillisecond)).TotalSeconds;
        decimal sec3 = (decimal)new TimeSpan((long)(0.8 * ticksPerMillisecond)).TotalSeconds;

        Console.WriteLine(sec);  
        // 0.0008  .NET Core 
        // 0.001   .NET Framework
        Console.WriteLine(sec2);
        // 0.0008  .NET Core
        // 0.0008  .NET Framework 
        Console.WriteLine(sec3);
        // 0.0008  .NET Core
        // 0.0008  .NET Framework

    }
}
```

[This blog post](https://carpediemsystems.co.uk/2018/11/08/timespan-frommilliseconds-rounding/) has further reading on the issue. Fiddle available at https://dotnetfiddle.net/YfIFjQ .